# What does this C# declaration mean?

Tags: c#, class, interface

In a C# program, I see the following declarations:

```
public class myForm : Form
public abstract myForm1 : myForm
public interface myInterface
public interface myInterface2 : myInterface
public class myClass : myForm1, myInterface2
```

What does myClass mean to have myForm1 and myInterface2?

Is myForm1 the base class?  If so, and there being no multiple inheritance in C#, what is this interface relationship to myClass?  How does an interface differ from a class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means `myClass` derives from the `myForm1` class, and implements the `myInterface2` interface. No multiple inheritance takes place because you only extend one class.

In Java this would be expressed with two different operators, C# just conveniently uses the `:` operator for both:

```
class myClass extends myForm1 implements myInterface2
```

An interface is not a class; it's (to put it simply) a list of methods that an implementing type needs to have (or a list of rules to follow).

Answer (score 2):

Fowler says,

> **Inheritance** and **subclassing** in OO languages is an implementation approach in which the subclass inherits the data and operations of the super class. It has a lot in common with **subtyping**, but there are important differences. Subclassing is only one way of implementing subtyping ... Subclassing can also be used without subtyping--but most authors rightly frown on this practice. Newer languages and standards increasingly try to emphasize the difference between **interface-inheritance** (subtyping) and **implementation-inheritance** (subclassing).
>
> Two questions arise concerning the relationship between an **object** and a **type**. First, does an object have **single type** that can inherit from supertypes (**single classification**), or does it have **several types** (**multiple classification**)? Multiple classification is different than **multiple inheritance**. With multiple inheritance a type can have many supertypes, but each instance is of a single type that may have supertypes. Multiple classification allows multiple types for an object without defining a specific type for the purpose.

Comment: +1 For addressing the underlying concepts: but consider including the appropriate links (or resources) from which the quotes were extracted and perhaps add additional information.